# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

This question on WebApps has been voted off-topic and closed:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17668/how-do-you-save-a-draft-of-a-published-article-in-joomla

I can't see any explanation. Why is it off-topic? And is there any other Stack Exchange site for which it would be considered on-topic?

Comment: See [Where can I ask a question about creating/developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)

Answer (score 13):

The question is off topic because it falls outside the scope defined in the Web Apps FAQ:

> [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

In particular:

> and it is not about...
>
> - Desktop software
> - Apps for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad
> - **Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB**
> - Web applications containing adult content
> - Developing web applications
> - Browsers and their features

Joomla falls into the category of "hosted scripts".

Web Apps is for questions about online Web Applications where said application is being provided in a "Software as a Service" manner (paid for, or free). i.e. you're not running it on your own server, you didn't deploy it and you generally have no access the the source code.

So as the FAQ says, it's for questions about web applications such as GMail, Twitter, Facebook, Google.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation. So where would one ask a question about Joomla then? Does SE have it covered? Also I'm curious as to why "hosted scripts" don't count... I mean, Joomla (and MediaWiki, Textpattern, whatever) all have frontends that *are* webapps. From my point of view, I use a Joomla CMS that I'm **not** running on my own server -- I'm just an editor, so to me it *is* software as a service. Why does it matter if one organisation develops the webapp and (several) others host instances of it? Seems like an odd restriction.

Comment: @callum well there is this http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2608/cms-development but if it's sufficiently programmery it could be asked on Stack Overflow -- it'd need to involve actual modifications to source code, which the question as stated does not.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jeff. So would it make sense to migrate the original question _"How do you save a draft of a published article in Joomla?"_ to CMS Development? My concern is that it's not a question about development, but about using a CMS UI as an end user. That's why I thought it was right for WebApps. (I didn't ask the original question btw; I just wrongly advised a friend that they should post it there.) What about changing the rules of WebApps, to allow questions about "hosted scripts" – as long as they're about using the webapp UI, rather than about installation/config etc?

Comment: @callum: No, it can't be moved because that site is still just a proposal. It happens that there is not always a Stack Exchange for every question. Personally, I think [wordpress.se] should have been expanded to cover all CMS/blog software, but that didn't happen.

Comment: @aleverett - From a recent conversation in chat, I know Robert Cartaino isn't keen on this proposed merger: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/62/cms-blog-proposals-merger, but it would go some way to satisfying the ever growing number of questions we see about various CMS tools and particularly about their operation and administration. It kinda seems like the missing piece of the puzzle to me.

Comment: @al I don't think that would work; it'd be like "extending" Android to cover iPhones.. community is a subtle thing.

Comment: @Jeff: Fair enough.

Comment: A question like that would most likely be at home on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.