# Where can I ask a question about creating/developing web applications?

Tags: support, stackexchange, site-recommendation

I'm *new* to this site<sup>1</sup>. I found it by googling but my question was closed with the following reason:

> This question is about creating/developing a web application.

If questions about creating / developing web applications are off-topic on this site, where can I ask this kind of questions?

I found this [If I'm working on a web app, do I ask here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/560/88163) but answer to that question only suggests [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [Web Masters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but I think that those sites have a too narrow scope for my needs.

NOTES:

1. Actually I'm not new, but I'm posting this on behalf of the new members that doesn't have yet the required reputation to post a question here.

Related

- [Web Applications not accepting questions about web applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4442/88163)

---

Markdown link to this question for using it on comments to off-topic questions:

`[Where can I ask a question about creating/developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [systems development life cicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) is very broad topic. There isn't a site on the Stack Exchange Network which scope embraces all the questions that could be made about all its phases even if you are focused on *web applications*.

- If you are starting from zero look for an online resource like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn.
- If your question is about administering a website checkout scope of [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- If your question is about developing a website using WordPress (WP or worpress.org) checkout the scope of [WordPress development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- If your question is about using web services checkout the scope of
  [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault/help/on-topic).
- If you are able to narrow the scope of your question look at [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691) or ask a site recommendation question on https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Other related site recommendation questions on Meta SE:

- [Where should I ask questions about web browsers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126139/289691).
- [Where should I post a question regarding web design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163193/289691).
- [Where can I ask a question about finding general software that meets certain requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411/289691).
  Several questions about where to ask for software library recommendations points to this question.
- [Showcase for user-created web applications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237357/289691).
- [Where should web hosting platform questions go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267599/289691).
- [Where should I ask a developer question about Google's web store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331697/289691).

---

## Sites Related to the Systems Development Lifecycle

### DevOps Stack Exchange

From https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour

> DevOps Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software engineers working on automated testing, continuous delivery, service integration and monitoring, and building SDLC infrastructure.

Their top 5 tags are [docker](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker), [kubernetes](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes), [jenkins](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenkins), [amazon-web-services](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), and [ansible](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansible).

### Graphic Design

[Tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).
*Checkout their scope on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [website-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)
- [interface-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-design)

### Server Fault

[Tour](https://serverfault.com/tour).
*Checkout their scope on https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic*.

### Software Engineering

[Tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour).
*Checkout their scope on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development)

### Software Recommendations

[Tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)
*Checkout their scope on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library)
- [programming](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming)
- [web-development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development)

### Stack Overflow

[Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
*Checkout their scope on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications)
- [web-development-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-development-server)

#### Stack Overflow FAQ

- [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/1595451)
- [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/1595451)

### Super User

[Tour](https://superuser.stackexchange.com/tour)
*Checkout their scope on https://superuser.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [web-development](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-development)

### User Experience

[Tour](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour)
*Checkout their scope on https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)

### Webmasters

[Tour](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour)
*Checkout their scope on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*.

Tags related to web applications

- [website-design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)
- [web-development](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development)
- [website-features](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-features)

## Related

- [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163)