# I asked for indication of sites/webtools and I am at risk of being blocked, where should I ask this type of question?

Tags: discussion

To be clearer, let's assume that I'm looking for a Cloud where I would simply upload the Python code and I can already create a Trigger every 5 minutes and let it run forever.

And I want to ask for directions on where I can do this, is it an acceptable question for *Web Applications* because it is an indication of a platform on the Web?

If it is acceptable, why am i getting this blocking risk notification?
If it is not acceptable, Is there any community that could point me to this type of question?

Comment: See [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)