# Is this site for application usage, but not development?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

Is this correct? If so, do you guys know where web development questions go?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this correct?

correct

> If so, do you guys know where web development questions go?

https://stackoverflow.com: JS is the most used tag (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags). PHP, HTML, CSS, jquery are all in the top 10 tags.

Comment: Thanks. StackOverflow really does not like webdev questions. I get that some of them may technically go there, but other sites that could be applicable would be helpful.

Comment: @BigMistake JS is the most used tag https://stackoverflow.com/tags . PHP, HTML, CSS, jquery are all in the top 10 tags.

Comment: @BigMistake Checkout [Where can I ask a question about creating/developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)